# Convert String with square brackets to PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string, values are in brackets and separated with comma, like array string:

Example:

```
[[["Name" , "ID"] , [12]] , ["Test" , 78] , 0]
```

How to convert this string to PHP array?

Comment: [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That's a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) string representation of an array, use `json_decode()`:

```
$array = json_decode($string);    
print_r($array);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Name
                    [1] => ID
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test
            [1] => 78
        )
    [2] => 0
)
```

If it had any `{ }` that would be an object and decoded as a `stdClass` object in PHP unless you pass `true` to `json_decode()` to force an array.

Since it's structured as a PHP array (as of PHP 5.4), this works as well (don't use `eval` on untrusted data).  **There is absolutely no reason to do this, it's just illustrative**:

```
eval("\$array = $string;");
print_r($array);
```