# Treat string as a multidimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a bunch of value pairs in a MySQL table, stored just as text. The values look like this:

`[[1560514777,1560515694]]`

If there's only one pair. Multiple pairs look like this:

`[[1560467640,1560468709],[1560470287,1560471705]]`

So when I retrieve these values, they're already in an array format. I need to use them as arrays, and rather than strip the first set of square brackets with regex, look for more brackets, explode the comma-separated values therein, then strip those brackets with regex, then try to reconstruct a multidimensional array, I'd like to just tell PHP to treat the string as an array as-is.

Is this possible? What's the easiest way to get PHP to identify this as an array?

Comment: There is a very similar question here : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440020/convert-string-with-square-brackets-to-php-array)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String with square brackets to PHP Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440020/convert-string-with-square-brackets-to-php-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just a json string. Use [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to decode it into a PHP-array:

```
$theString = '[[1560467640,1560468709],[1560470287,1560471705]]';

$array = json_decode($theString, true);
```

`$array` is now an ordinary array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1560467640
            [1] => 1560468709
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1560470287
            [1] => 1560471705
        )
)
```

Here's a [demo](https://3v4l.org/MogI5)

Comment: That was it. I just didn't know what I was looking at. Thank you.

Comment: "Use json_encode() to turn it into an array" - you mean `json_decode()`, right?

Comment: @user7290573 - You're absolutely correct. I was a bit too quick for my own good :-) Updated. Thanks!